# Subdividing a beveled mesh creates new vertices in wrong places

Tags: mesh, vertices

A new vertice forms when the object is being subdivided.

I beveled my mesh and added a subdivision surface modifier, and now a new face/vertices are created where the black areas are:

[image: z]

It appears that when the mesh has the modifier active, the subdivided mesh goes to a singular point in the center:
[image]

I applied Rotation and Scale to the mesh already after it was edited. Nothing changed.

How do I get rid of the odd mesh warp when my mesh is subdivided?
I want to get the center curve near the bottom to be as smooth as possible, without signs of low poly mesh. Like a perfect part-circle.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you have a face made up of more than *4 vertices* (**N-GON**), and with the subdivided surface, you have to be careful, and try to use a more regular topology. Ngons will not subdivide correctly.

[image]

I used the command **crtl + T** to triangulate the face.
[image: NGON converted to triangular]