# Mesh with Triangulate Modifier mesh causes new faces and vertices to form with the Subsurface Modifier and Bevel Modifier

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

**OLD TITLE:** ***Smooth mesh to hide the low poly subdivisions***

Title of the question changed, as the main issue seems to be that with the triangulate modifier and the subdivision modifier, there are new faces and vertices being created.

**New question:**

Using the Bevel Modifier, Triangulate Modifier, and the Subdivision Modifier, new vertices are being formed as you can see in the second image. I would like it to look like the first image, except with the Subdivision Surface modifier working, so the cutout loos smooth.

Beveling with no Limit only shows these two problems:

[image]

New Blend File:

[image]

---

**Old question:**

I created a cutout of a cylinder in my mesh. I beveled it, and it gives me this:

[image]

I would like to 'smooth' the edges to look like a nice curve, and not blocky.

I used a Subdivision Surface modifier, but:
[image]

I already tried going around using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, but I could not get rid of them all, and it made my mesh look messy.

Is there a better way for me to subdivide it without the vertices going nuts?

[image]

**EDIT:**

R.M's method below works up to an extent. It curves the cutout, but the face deforms appear still. Is this more of an issue with my mesh?

[image]

With no Bevel Limit, the corners are sharp at the front of the mesh, but the bottom still has the corners warping in. With the Angle, it makes the mesh more round/smoother, how I want it, but the bottom still has the mesh warps. As well as the front corners.

Comment: This is caused by n-gons for sure. Try to use only quad faces.

Comment: I tried, such as removing that line at the bottom, but it would only go away if the faces around it went with it.

Comment: [I don't see warping with `no limit`](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4410). The only problem I'm noticing is that the round parts are not smooth, but you may have to go back to change this (use cylinders with more detail).

Comment: It's at the bottom for me. Three corners bevel inwards. Also, around the mesh, it appears that two faces are in the same location at some places, creating a dark shading in a few places near corners.

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is coming from: the order of the modifiers! Check the .blend file I linked: triangulate first, then bevel, then subdivide.

Comment: With that order, it somewhat helps. [It creates these odd 'pulls' in a couple of places though.](https://i.imgur.com/J9Ao4WW.png)

Comment: More `segments` reduce the problem, but I don't think it can be eliminated without manually working with the mesh.

Comment: I see you accepted the answer but in comments you're not yet satisfied: if still so, I can suggest to see other similar questions with more examples and solutions: eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98369/how-to-get-rid-of-subsurf-overhangs and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap

Comment: Thanks! I ended up remodeling it, and beveled it a bit more to smooth it out. I had this similar problem, and manually using the knife tool, I made extra cuts so most faces had around 6-8 vertices, and the issue was fixed.

Comment: You have two large ngons (Polygons with more than 4 vertices). Those subdivide incorrectly. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98613/subdividing-a-beveled-mesh-creates-new-vertices-in-wrong-places/98614#98614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to triangulate the faces manually, you can use the `triangulate` modifier. Then, add a `bevel` modifier, and a `subdivision surface` modifier:

[image: Modifiers]

This gives the following result:

[image: model]

Be sure to triangulate *before* subdividing!

I'm noticing that some of the circles are still "blocky". To fix this, try to go back, before you beveled it, and use a *bevel* modifier (not to be confused with the one above), setting a limit on the angle. Example:

**No limit**:

[image: no limit]

**With limit** (note that the less pointy edges were not affected, and will be smoothed out by a subdivision surface modifier):
[image: with limit]

Comment: Yeah, the bottom has a curved new face appearing still. I'll try the bevel modifier.

Comment: Yeah, the bottom has a curved new face appearing still. I'll try the bevel modifier. It smooths it out, but the odd faces keep appearing at the bottom, and at the front foot corner. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/GILJP87.png)

Comment: @Akados ah, I see that problem too, now. You can use a bevel modifier between the other two to fix that problem. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Did what you said, but I still get the problem. I updated my question if that helps.